# Does the session expire if the user is sent to external resource for sometime?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, web-applications, session-variables

From my application a logged in user  is sent to an external application to complete the `OAuth` process

[image]

As the user clicks *Authorize App*, user is sent to the callback url (i.e back to the applicaton).

Now, when I try to print some session variables saved earlier, I get `null`. Why is that ? Does the session expire because of these calls ?

Here is what happens :

```
user logs into the application ---->session created for him---->sent to external
                                                                app to complete
                                                                the OAuth process
                                                                  |
  session variable prints null<--redirected back to application <--
```

Comment: Try printing session id before and after and see if a new session was created instead of old one. Although this should not happen. You can also take a look at session cookie in browser if it changed. If it changes, then obviously your older values are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the redirect URL, OAuth provider returns the token to your server. you need to update the session if the authentication is successful. So the redirect URL that you have given to OAuth provider has to handle that.